# Reading javascript from xml

Tags: javascript, xml, razor

I have a list of strings I want to put in a XML file and include the file into the web pages. So when I do validation on client side using javascript. I can read those strings from the XML and parse it immediately.
Something like this

```
blabla.cshtml
<includebla> path to xml </includebla>
<script type="javascript">
read xml
parse string
</script>
```

The point is: I want to keep my strings in a file so the browser won't download the data again and  again, but I don't know if I can reference a XML file in .cshtml and read it in javascript. Can anybody give a hint? I really appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: Are you tied to xml? I'd say JSON would be an easier format to deal with in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If its just a list of strings, consider putting them in a JS object and include a link to JS file in your cshtml.

**resources.js**

```
var resources = {
      "id1": "sample string 1",
      "id2": "sample string 2",
      "id3": "sample string 3",
}
```

In your JS file, you can then say:

**site.js**

```
function getStringById(id) {
    return resources[id];
}
```

You escape the rigor of XML parsing and JS files can be cached easily by browser.

```
alert(getStringById("id1"));
```